# Как делать сложные анимации?

Tags: android, анимация

Как вообще в приложении на платформе android делаются сложные анимации. Хотя бы что-то типа закрытия и открытия глаз например. Хотелось бы узнать поподробнее. Есть картинки людей, нужно анимировать мимику лица. Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно посмотреть в сторону [подобной библиотечки](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android), и делать анимации не средствами Android.

Еще можно с помощью OpenGL отрисовывать то, что вам нужно, но этот путь еще сложнее.